# Problema al cerrar etiqueta con jquery (prepend,before)

Tags: jquery

```
$.each( elements, function(i, val){
    $('#tbl').prepend('<tr>').addClass('tr');
        $('.tr').before('<td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+$(val).val()+'</td>');
           $('#tbl').prepend('</tr>');

});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**alements** proeviene de un conjuto de input de un formulario

El tr permanece abierto

al añadir nuevos datos se recorren en la misma fila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de usar `prepend`, puedes usar `appendTo`.  Ademas `before` agrega los elementos antes del elemento seleccionado.  En su lugar puedes usar `append`.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$("#Add").on('click', function add() {
  var elements = $('input');
  $.each( elements, function(i, val){
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('#tbl');    
    tr.addClass('tr');
        tr.append('<td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+$(val).val()+'</td>');           

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl"></table>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<button id="Add">Add</button>
```